# Searching by filed containing a comma in Elasticsearch

Tags: search, elasticsearch

We have users in our system and their nicknames can contain commas which is the special character that Elasticsearch uses for separate values. I have the following users stored:

```
 {
    "nickname" : "John"
 }

 {
    "nickname" : "John,2"
 }
```

If I execute the query `nickname:John` I get both documents what is not the expected.

I am not sure of what I need. I mean a tokenizer, an analyzer...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Another question you have to ask yourself: do you want `john` to match `John`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String fields are analyzed by default in ElasticSearch, that's why your 2nd user is indexed with 2 terms : "John" and "2" and match your `nickname:John` query.

If you want your nickname not to be analyzed (treated as a single string), you have to explicitly set the mapping of this field to "keyword".

More information about that : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-analyzer/ and about the mapping API : http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-put-mapping/

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for. Now I have to deal with the MongoDB river.